# Combining rows and filter with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a data frame with some values:
[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnaMk.png)

```
data = [10,30,50,80,90,100,120]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1'])
```

And I want to filter all the rows combinations that match with some value, exemple:
All combinations that matches with 130:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Ub4.png)

```
result = [[10,120],[50,80],[30,100]]
```

Or result as index

```
result = [[0,6],[2,3],[1,5]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by row combinations?? Please share your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.